# Metacello says "This package"?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, metacello

I am using pharo 4. I just installed a configuration which load other configurations, and I am getting this error:

```
This package depends on the following classes:
  GTExampleTestCase
  GTExampleFinder
You must resolve these dependencies before you will be able to load these definitions: 
  RTExampleFinder
  gtExampleInstance
  class:selector:method:to:
  newExample
  RTExampleTestCase
  packageNames

Select Proceed to continue, or close this window to cancel the operation.
```

How do I know which package is "this"?

Comment: Where is this, it does not appear in what you have shown

Comment: That is the point, nowhere is such information displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, that's a known problem. What you can do is use the debugger to go back a couple of frames to the method `#loadWithNameLike:`. The argument to that method will be the name of the package.

Answer (score 1):

And in this concrete case, GTExampleFinder is currently in GT-Inspector-Examples-Utils. And as you are installing Roassal2 in Pharo 4, you might run into some trouble. Roassal2 is being developed in Pharo 5, and the Metacello configuration of Roassal2 does not use semantic versioning

Answer (score 1):

If you open a Transcript, when the warning is raised, you should have the current details of the loading in it. The package loading should be in the last line.